# Comma in a macro to pass arguments to a another macro function ( #define a,b )

Tags: c, function, macros, arguments

I am using CodeVision to program AVR micro controller. It is a C compiler.

So this is the part is giving me an error

```
#defined some_name PORTL,6
SETBIT ( some_name );
```

the error is:
too few parameters in macro call

the definition of the macro according to CodeVision is:
The following macros are available:

```
SETBIT(port,b)

            sets bit b of port to logic 1 state.

Example:

/* set bit 5 of I/O Port A output to logic 1 for non-XMEGA chips */
SETBIT(PORTA,5);
```

After reading some stuff about macro which are far from my level of understanding I noticed that they use this

```
#define comma ,
```

So i tried this and my new error was the same as old one.

I have read some post about macro but they were to advanced for me to understand. So could you please tell me what is the solution. Could you also tell me where I can find a place to teach me macros step by step from easy ones to crazy hard ones that I saw in other posts.

sorry if the answer is too obvious, I did not know how to search for it to get exact problem as the one I am facing.

Thank You

Comment: Why not using variadic macro ?

Comment: @haaks the SETBIT() macro is defined by the toolchain header.

Comment: @Clifford; So, he can't modify that?

Comment: @haccks : Of course he could, but it is ill-advised.  A toolchain upgrade might overwrite his changes. And in a team environment, every developer would need the modified header.  Simple enough to define your own macro of course - so your suggestion has merit.

Comment: I only have access to header file, which i do not think is going to help. Jens Gustedit answer worked.
Anyways seems that you guys really know what you are talking about, could you introduce a reference with a lot of examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is the order of expansion, `some_name` is only seen as part of the only argument of `SETBIT`

```
#define SETBIT1(ARG) SETBIT(ARG)

SETBIT1(some_name)
```

should work

Comment: I made mistake wait, let me try again

Answer (score 1):

You might look at it differently and define a macro thus:

```
#defined BIT_NAME() SETBIT( PORTL, 6 )

BIT_NAME();
```

If you need a set/clear macro then:

```
#defined BIT_NAME( b ) (b ? SETBIT( PORTL, 6 ) : CLRBIT( PORTL, 6 ) )

BIT_NAME( 1 );
BIT_NAME( 0 );
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion too. But the structure of my program will look better if I use the other suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry that I can't choose both as the answer :(

Comment: @user2312842 : Just choose the one you actually decided to use.  Jens solution directly answers your question, while mine side-steps the question by suggesting an alternative.